# Tile on a bathroom shower ceiling or just mildew-resistant paint in a dry climate?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

Location is Colorado Springs, where we have a fairly dry climate but are not immune to mildew. We are remodeling, turning the old shower into a linen closet and the old bathtub area (a long jacuzzi tub) into a shower. We did have mildew of tiles and painted areas in the old shower.

The old/new bathroom is enclosed. The ventilation is via a new attic fan that will be very close overhead to the new shower.

What benefit can we reasonably expect from tiling the shower ceiling vs. just using mildew-resistant paint? We believe that tiling the shower ceiling is at least $1,000. We are willing to pay it if it's reasonable to expect real benefits.

**Update from the husband**

1. We are considering tiling the shower ceiling to reduce the instances of mold or mildew high on the walls as well as on the ceiling. Even though we have a dry climate in Colorado, long, hot showers can cause severe moisture problems, even affecting the woodwork, despite good ventilation.
2. *To Tim B's comment*: The ‘attic fan’ is an-appropriately-sized 150 cfm fan at the entrance to the new shower. It has a 6” insulated vent pipe, and will exit through the roof by the end of next month (all of this is an in-process project). To your excellent point, the old fan did vent into the attic, a practice that used to be acceptable, for some strange reason.
3. *To Jimmy Fix-it's comment*: You are exactly right: $1000 is ridiculous, which is what brought this subject up. The shower will be approximately 45” x 96” (based on the width of our bathroom on that side; that drives the cost of the tile). The shower wall tile is rectified porcelain 12” x 24” in a Carrera Marble look, and is nice, but expensive. Instead of repeating that in the ceiling, at the current price, we are considering smaller, and less-expensive 12” x 12” inch white porcelain tiles at ¼ the price.
4. In addition, the ceiling is where the much more expensive, epoxy-based grout is most important, because of its mold/mildew resistance. That was another key part of the $1k.
5. The biggest issue is neutralizing the mildew/mold impact of lengthy, hot-water showers.

(*Note from the wife*: He's not shower-shaming. He wants to make me happy and have confidence in the best solution. We do realize that wipe-downs after showers are key.)

**Some interesting links about tiling** … almost all are in favor of it, but some suggest less expensive—and maybe smaller—white tile. Note that others prefer larger.

- http://www.conestogatile.com/tips-and-trends/should-i-tile-my-shower-ceiling/
- https://www.houzz.com/discussions/228606/should-the-ceiling-of-a-shower-be-tiled
- https://www.houzz.com/discussions/4545946/help-should-i-tile-the-shower-ceiling-or-not
- http://www.sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?126243-Tiling-ceiling-above-shower-Pros-and-Cons

**Interesting link about mold on grout**

- http://ths.gardenweb.com/discussions/2282369/tiling-ceiling-in-shower-is-it-over-kill
- http://floorelf.com/how-to-install-tile-on-a-shower-ceiling

**And how to avoid paying $75 a bag for thinset**

- https://www.bobvila.com/posts/96018-ceramic-tile-on-bathroom-ceiling?page=1#.Wc7ckWiPJaQ

Comment: what do you mean attic fan? You don't have an exhaust fan in this bathroom do you that vents into the attic, correct? You mean a ceiling fan that routes its exhaust tubing/ductwork through the attic to the outside?

Comment: With decent ventilation you don't need to tile the ceiling to prevent mildew. Make sure you use glossy paint in there. BTW, $1000 is ridiculous.

Comment: @ Tim B and @ Jimmy Fix-it -- See updates to original post.